# How to test a configuration class in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I have the following Spring Boot configuration class so that an index is created in our MongoDB:

```
@Configuration
@DependsOn("mongoTemplate")
@Profile({ "!test" })
public class CollectionsConfig {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    CollectionsConfig(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initIndexes() {
        mongoTemplate.indexOps("db-name"); // collection name string or .class
            .ensureIndex(
                new Index().on("fechaAlta", Sort.Direction.ASC).expire(15552000)
        );
    }
}
```

How could I test this since this class doesn't create any bean or anything like that? I have seen examples of configuration classes where they use the application context to test if a bean is created, but I am not creating any bean here so I don't know what to do to run this code.

Help please.

Comment: This must be useful for you https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/07/testing-auto-configurations-with-spring-boot-2-0

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume a meaningful way to test this configuration would be to verify the side effects of the `@PostConstruct`-annotated method.

For example, you could have a `@SpringBootTest` loading this configuration, then have your test verify that on your embedded version of Mongo DB the index on `fechaAlta` has been successfully created.

An ***alternative*** would be writing a test where you manually instantiate `CollectionsConfig`, pass it a mocked `MongoTemplate` instance, manually invoke the `@PostConstruct`-annotated method and ultimately verify the expected interactions with the `MongoTemplate` are satisfied.